# Create POST request with JSON params

Tags: swift, xcode

How to create a POST request as follows:

**KEY** = params

**VALUE** = {"api_key": "abc123"}

Eg. POST: params=value

```
let resourceURL = "https://127.0.0.1"
let apiKey:String = "abc123"

let params = ["api_key": apiKey] as Dictionary<String, String>
    do {
        let jsonParams = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: .sortedKeys)
    
    } catch {
        print("Error in JSON.")
    }

var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: resourceURL)!)
let headers = ["Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]
                
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
```

Example request from postman:

[image]

Comment: I wanted to send it as KEY = params, I did the edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make x-www-form-urlencoded body try something like this:

```
var comps = URLComponents()
comps.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "params", value: "{\"api_key\": \"abc123\"}")]
request.httpBody = comps.query?.data(using: .utf8)
```

You may check more details in this [article](https://medium.com/@serge.works.io/swift-how-to-create-a-http-post-request-with-application-x-www-form-urlencoded-body-bfd9cd26d6d5)